# Matlab plotting inside a for loop issue

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, plot

I have written a code to plot a function inside a loop. For every value number of the loop (*n = 4:4:32*), I have some variables which change by that value and here comes the problem.
If I don't use the for loop, my plot is what it has to be, while using the loop it doesn't because my function is evaluated acording to *n* but the variables do not.

I don't understand why does it happen: for n=12, for example, shouldn't be both plot images the same?. I uplodaded two images, both for *n=12*, the first without using the loop and the second one using the loop.

1st image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1qhA.png
2nd image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksMuI.png

### The code

```
a = -1; b = 3;
lambda = [];
xx = linspace(a,b,1000);
df = prac8fun2(xx);

for n = 4:4:32
D = zeros(n+1,n+1);   
x = linspace(a,b,n+1);

    for jj = 1:n+1
        lambdaj = (-1)^(n-(jj-1)).*nchoosek(n,jj-1);
        lambda = [lambda, lambdaj];             
    end
lambda = lambda.*((n^n)/(factorial(n)*(b-a)^n));

    for jj = 1:n+1
        for ii = 1:n+1
          if ii == jj
              D(ii,jj) = sum((x(jj)-[x(1:jj-1), x(jj+1:end)]).^(-1));
            else
              D(ii,jj) = lambda(jj)./(lambda(ii)).*(x(ii)-x(jj)).^(-1);
            end
    end  
    end

Df = D*prac8fun(x)';

plot(xx,df,'k','linewidth',2); hold on;
plot(x,Df,'-or'); grid on;

pause
close

end
```

Note: prac8fun as well as prac8fun2 are functions saved in a different .m file.

*Parag*

> please explain your problem with respect to the variables in your code. The problem is not clear to me at least

I don't know how to explain myself better, so I uploaded a video showing my issue.
Video (must replace htp with http): htp://youtu.be/dWredX5z8XY

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: please explain your problem with respect to the variables in your code. The problem is not clear to me at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in your handling of `lambda`.  It starts off as [], but you append the values created in that first loop, and never reset it.  So by the third loop (n = 12), lambda ends up with length 1 x 27, but you only index values between 1 and 13 to create `D`.

On the other hand, if you remove the outer loop and use n = 12, `lambda` starts off [] and you fill 13 values into it, which is probably the behaviour you want.

You can check this by checking the size and contents of `lambda` after running without the loop with `n=12`, and after running with the loop set to `n = 4:4:12`.  To fix it, I would recommend that you preallocate the size of lambda at the start of the loop as you do for `D`, and fill using direct indexing (`lambda(jj) = lambdaj`).

**Generally speaking**: avoid appending values wherever possible. If you are in a situation where you have no choice but to use the `x = [x,newx];` format, particularly in nested loops, keep a close eye on the size and contents of your variable.